# How to merge the Two Columns with two different Tables without getting duplicates in either of the resulting columns

Tags: excel, dax, powerquery

I have 3 tables.

Table One

```
Old Pack Name   Composition
Pack 1          ABC
Pack 1          BCD
Pack 1          CDE
Pack 1          DEF
Pack 2          ABC
Pack 2          CDE
Pack 2          DEF
Pack W          ABC
Pack W          BCD
Pack W          CDE
Pack W          DEF
Pack W          XZE
```

Table 2

```
New Pack Name   Composition
New Pack A          ABC
New Pack A          BCD
New Pack A          CDE
New Pack D          ABC
New Pack D          CDE
New Pack D          DEF
New Pack D          GQH
New Pack 1          ABC
New Pack 1          BCD
New Pack 1          CDE
New Pack 1          XZE
New Pack 1          WER
New Pack 1          POU
```

and Table 3,  Which has the respective counterparts from old and new systems.

```
Old Pack Name   New Pack Name
Pack 1          New Pack A
Pack 2          New Pack D
Pack W          New Pack 1
```

In order to Present and manage the differences in both the systems I need to present the final data as below,

```
Old Pack Name   Old Composition Status  New Pack Name   New Composition STATUS
Pack 1          ABC         KEPT            New Pack A          ABC          --
Pack 1          BCD         KEPT            New Pack A          BCD          --
Pack 1          CDE         KEPT            New Pack A          CDE          --
Pack 1          DEF         REMOVED                                 
Pack 2          ABC         KEPT            New Pack D          ABC          --
Pack 2          CDE         KEPT            New Pack D          CDE          --
Pack 2          DEF         KEPT            New Pack D          DEF          --
                                            New Pack D          GQH         NEW
Pack W          ABC         KEPT            New Pack 1          ABC          --
Pack W          BCD         KEPT            New Pack 1          BCD          --
Pack W          CDE         KEPT            New Pack 1          CDE          --
Pack W          DEF         REMOVED         New Pack 1          XZE          --
Pack W          XZE         KEPT            New Pack 1          WER         NEW
                                            New Pack 1          POU         NEW
```

Currently I am doing it in excel, using multiple Filter Functions, Vstack, and Hstack,but I am unable to scale this solution for hundreds of Packs.  I am trying to do it in Power BI, but after merging and expanding the Old Pack Composition, merging with New Composition (With New Pack Name) gives too many extra rows. I need the Solution in Power Query or Dax.

Currently getting the results like below in Power Query.

[image]
Is there any way of solving this ?

Comment: This is rather a work assignment than a general coding question. Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ) so that others could benefit from a solution too. Things to consider:
[Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work:

*Assume your tables as named are read into three separate queries*
*Could read them all in to a single query, but this method is simpler if you are not used to writing code directly into the Advanced Editor.*

```
let

//Merge Tables 1 and 3
    Source = Table.NestedJoin(Table_1, {"Old Pack Name"}, Table_3, {"Old Pack Name"}, "Table_3", JoinKind.FullOuter),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Custom", each [Table_3][New Pack Name]{0}, type text),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Table_3"}),

//Add Index column for sorting the end results
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),

//Merge above with Table 2
//then remove unneeded columns
    #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Added Index", 
        {"Custom", "Composition"}, Table_2, {"New Pack Name", "Composition"}, "Table_2", JoinKind.FullOuter),
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Merged Queries",{"Custom"}),

//Expand and rename the merged table columns
    #"Expanded Table_2" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns1", "Table_2", {"New Pack Name", "Composition"}, {"New Pack Name", "New Composition"}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Expanded Table_2",{{"Composition", "Old Composition"}}),

//add custom columns for STATUS and "Composition Status"
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Renamed Columns", "STATUS", 
        each if [Old Pack Name] = null then "NEW" else null, type text),
    #"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom1", "Composition Status", 
        each if [New Pack Name] = null then "REMOVED" else if [Old Pack Name] <> null then "KEPT" else null, type text),

//set proper column order
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Added Custom2",
        {"Old Pack Name", "Old Composition", "Composition Status", "New Pack Name", "New Composition", "STATUS"}),

//Fill Down Index column for sorting
// then sort into desired order
    #"Filled Down" = Table.FillDown(#"Reordered Columns",{"Index"}),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Filled Down",{{"Index", Order.Ascending}, {"STATUS", Order.Ascending}}),
    #"Removed Columns2" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Sorted Rows",{"Index"})
in
    #"Removed Columns2"
```

[image]

[image]